# I cannot load my excel file though openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

there.
I cannot load my excel file though openpyxl.
the file is 1,402KB.
I tried to do New excel file. it can be opened.
but my excel file show below error.

this is error

```
D:\1.업무\Python\venv\Scripts\python.exe D:/1.업무/Python/AVDD.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/1.업무/Python/AVDD.py", line 5, in <module>
    wb = load_workbook(filename)
  File "D:\1.업무\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 312, in load_workbook
    reader.read()
  File "D:\1.업무\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 273, in read
    apply_stylesheet(self.archive, self.wb)
  File "D:\1.업무\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\styles\stylesheet.py", line 189, in apply_stylesheet
    stylesheet = Stylesheet.from_tree(node)
  File "D:\1.업무\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\styles\stylesheet.py", line 103, in from_tree
    return super(Stylesheet, cls).from_tree(node)
  File "D:\1.업무\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py", line 104, in from_tree
    return cls(**attrib)
  File "D:\1.업무\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\styles\stylesheet.py", line 93, in __init__
    self._normalise_numbers()
  File "D:\1.업무\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\styles\stylesheet.py", line 166, in _normalise_numbers
    fmt = BUILTIN_FORMATS[style.numFmtId]
KeyError: 56
```

and this my code.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.drawing.image import Image

filename="1.xlsx"
wb = load_workbook(filename)
print("done")
```

Comment: it's an issue for an older version, but looks relevant https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/482/invalidfileexception-unicode-e-in-v224

Comment: @buran Thank you for reply. I use 2.6.0 version it is last version

Comment: The problem is the same: Excel uses a locale-specific builtin style that openpyxl doesn't know. Looking at the specification I can see seveal completely different possible formats with the id 56. Please provide a sample file on the linked issue and we can continue the discussion there.

Comment: @CharlieClark i upload it. Thanks